# Cauchy principal value example

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I am learning about cauchy principal value integrals and was looking for help evaluating the integral given by

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-a}^{-\epsilon} \dfrac{A}{x} dx + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\epsilon}^a \dfrac{B}{x} dx 
\end{align}

where $A$ and $B$ are constants. My attempt so far is:

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-a}^{-\epsilon} \dfrac{A}{x} dx + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\epsilon}^a \dfrac{B}{x} dx  
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} [A(\ln \epsilon - \ln a)+B(\ln a - \ln \epsilon )]
\end{align}

If $A = B$, then I can cancel out the $\ln \epsilon$ terms and the principal value is 0. However, I would like to know how to determine the principal value if $A \neq B$.

Comment: It is rather unusual to look for the PV (Principal Value) of a function that is different on the left and on the right of the singularity.

Comment: From my understanding, Cauchy's principal value can sometimes be found using the residue theorem. In cases where we use Jordan's lemma and find the residue around an arc with angle $\phi$, wouldn't we encounter integrals that are different along the left and right side of the singularity?

Answer (score 0):

If $A > B$ the the principal value is $-\infty$.  If $A < B$ then the principal value is $+\infty$.